# MySQL Syntax : "the right syntax to use near" - right in the beginning

Tags: mysql, syntax

I am a MySQL-noob and today I tried to setup a MySQL call which is more than 5 lines long. I keep getting syntax errors which I try to fix for hours, but I don't have a clue what the problem is. Here is the code:

```
USE myDatabase;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MYPROC()
BEGIN

SET @ID      = 1;
SET @maxID   = 3;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE resultTable(v DOUBLE, ttc DOUBLE);

WHILE (@ID < @maxID) DO

 INSERT partTable1.v, partTable2.ttc 
 INTO 
    resultTable 
 FROM
    (SELECT * FROM
            (((SELECT time_sec, v FROM speedTable WHERE (trip_id = @ID)) as partTable1) 
            INNER JOIN 
        ((SELECT time_sec, ttc FROM sightsTable WHERE (trip_id = @ID)) as partTable2)  ON
                (0.04 > abs(partTable1.time_sec - partTable2.time_sec)))
    );


SET @ID := @ID + 1;
END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER;

CALL MYPROC();

SELECT * FROM resultTable LIMIT 100;
```

Is there anything obvious that needs to be corrected?

Update1: Added semicolon to the "CREATE.."-statement, now first three statements are OK.

Update2: Added 3 more semicolons!

Update3: Followed the suggestion to make it a function + separate function call. Error message changed!

Update4: I fixed the issues mentioned in the two answers. Still something wrong there. See updated code above and error message below.

Updated error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
nual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
ear ' partTable2.ttc
    INTO
            resultTable
    FROM
            (SELECT * FROM
                    (((SELE' at line 11
```

Kind Regards,
Theo

Comment: Show the *whole* error message

Comment: The most obvious correction required is sharing the actual error message.

Comment: If you're executing all statements at once you might want to add semicolons at the end of each statement.

Comment: Add a semicolon after your CREATE statement

Comment: Add a semicolon after you declare the temp table.

Comment: Semicolon added, error message updated.

Comment: More semicolons after the two SET statements: 
`SET @partTable1 = (SELECT time_sec, v FROM speedTable WHERE (trip_id = @ID));` ..... and ......
 
`SET @partTable2 = (SELECT time_sec, ttc FROM sightsTable WHERE (trip_id = @ID));`

Comment: And after the insert. `(0.04 > abs(partTable1.time_sec - partTable2.time_sec)));`

Comment: 3 more semicolons added, error message updated.

Answer (score 0):

Flow control statements, of which `WHILE` is one, can only be used within a stored procedure, but you are attempting to use it as a plain query via the console.

If you absolutely must take this path (using mysql instead of an application language), create a store procedure with the code you want, then call it.

Creating the procedure would look like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MYPROC()
BEGIN
WHILE (@ID < @maxID) DO
    SET @partTable1 = (SELECT time_sec, v FROM speedTable WHERE (trip_id = @ID));
    SET @partTable2 = (SELECT time_sec, ttc FROM sightsTable WHERE (trip_id = @ID));

    INSERT v, ttc INTO resultTable FROM
         (@partTable1 INNER JOIN @partTable2 ON
              (0.04 > abs(partTable1.time_sec - partTable2.time_sec)));

    SET @ID := @ID + 1;
END WHILE;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then to call it:

```
CALL MYPROC();
```

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f0f3/1) of a simplified version of this working.

Note that you do have one syntax error:

```
@ID = @ID + 1; -- incorrect syntax
SET @ID := @ID + 1; -- correct
```

Answer (score 0):

Still some syntactic problems and functionality problems...

- You can't use `WHILE` in SQL scripts. You can use `WHILE` only in the body of a stored routine. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flow-control-statements.html
- You can't use `SET` to assign multiple columns to a scalar. MySQL doesn't support relation-valued variables, only scalar variables. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-statement.html
- You can `INSERT` from the results of a query with a join, but the query must be introduced with `SELECT`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html
- You can't use session variables as the names of tables. You would have to use a prepared statement. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/prepare.html But that opens a whole different can of worms, and doing it wrong can be a security vulnerability (see http://xkcd.com/327). I wouldn't recommend you start using prepared statements as a self-described MySQL-noob.

This problem is probably simpler than you're making it. You don't need a temporary table, and you don't need to read the results one row at a time.

Here's an example that I think does what you intend:

```
USE myDatabase
SET @ID      = 1;
SET @maxID   = 3;

SELECT sp.v, si.ttc
FROM speedTable AS sp
INNER JOIN sightsTable AS si
    ON (sp.trip_id = si.trip_id AND 0.04 > ABS(sp.time_sec - si.time_sec))
WHERE sp.trip_id BETWEEN @ID AND @maxID;
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your piece of code and I get the following error: 'ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE sp.trip_id BETWEEN @ID AND '@maxID' at line 5'

Comment: I omitted a closing parenthesis, and I've fixed it by editing the above. By the way, as a programmer you should have been able to spot that mistake and correct it yourself.

Comment: Ok, now your code runs without errors but I had to stop it after 10 minutes without a result. The problem is, that I really need to split up the two datasets with @ID first, because both have millions of entries and complexity explodes.

Comment: I applied all of your correction suggestions, could you please take a look?

Comment: There's no `FROM` in an INSERT statement. It's just `INSERT INTO <table> SELECT ...` Please read the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html